# IntelliJ Recent grails commands

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

How can I clear history of recent grails commands from the Run Grails Command (RunTarget) dialog dialog?

[image: dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it from the UI, but you can remove the unwanted values from `<user_home>\.Intellij<version>\config\options\options.xml` under the `grails.command.history` property name.

Just delete the values you don't want and restart the app.

```
<property name="grails.command.history" value="clean" />
```

You can also just delete the entire grails.command.history line which'll remove all entries.